# Center titleView in navigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I've added a `UIPageControl` to the `titleView` in the `navigationItem`, but the issue is that it is not centered due to I only have a `leftBarButton`. Is it possible to create a `rightBarButtonItem` which is hidden so the `UIPageControl` is centered?

Comment: Yes you can create a right bar button and hide it. But titleView is centered by default. So are you saying that it is not centered in the remaining space left by the one other button or that it is not the center of the bar?

Comment: it is centered in the remaining space left by the leftBarButton

Comment: it's not centered if the leftBarButtonItem isn't the same size as rightBarButtonItem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [center custom title in UINavigationBar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921026/center-custom-title-in-uinavigationbar)