# Centre align the nav bar title on swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

After installed the right hand bar buttons my page title become dealigned. Is there a way to realign it in the centre of the page?

Haven't found a way to do in with the storyboard, but I imagine that may be possible programmatically?!

[image]

Comment: May be duplicated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921026/center-custom-title-in-uinavigationbar

Comment: Explain how you make the title.

Comment: Similar issue, but I think I made clear on the question and tags I am looking for a solution using swift syntax, not objective C. Not to mention deprecated methods from objective C that no longer work on Swift.

Comment: I have a navigation controller, that controls this view. So the title has been written using the storyboard. It is not programmatically done. The buttons are also done using the storyboard. I've inserted a view onto the navbar and buttons into this view. So, all storyboard done.

Comment: Did you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your title might be too wide.
Try to add a background color and see how much it's span.

I had a similar issue.

What I did is to add an empty image on the left side to balance the nav bar:

```
private func alignWithWhiteSpace() -> UIBarButtonItem
{
    let menuBtn = UIButton()

    menuBtn.userInteractionEnabled = true
    menuBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)
    menuBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "empty image"), forState: .Normal)

    let menuBtnItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    menuBtnItem.customView = menuBtn
    return menuBtnItem
}
```